# Почему copy не работает?

Tags: python

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.info={"name":"hi","objs":{"h":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":10,"height":10,'type':'image',"src":"hello","image":pygame.image.load("hello")}}}
    def save(self):
        c=self.info.copy()
        for obj in c['objs']:
            if obj['type']=='image':
                if obj['src']: del obj['image']
```

После кода почему, то из объекта удаляется глобально "image", из-за чего это?

Comment: Скорее всего, внутренние объекты не копируются. Попробуйте функцию `copy.deepcopy` из модуль `copy`

Comment: TypeError: cannot pickle 'pygame.Surface' object

Comment: Он выдаёт эту ошибку при copy.deepcopy

Comment: Вручную делайте копию, либо для работы deepcopy вместо `pygame.image.load` что-нибудь другое использовать, например оставить имя файла, а в нужных местах загружать его через `pygame.image.load`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`copy` производит то, что называется *shallow copy*, то есть копирует только *references* их одного объекта в другой.

Вы же хотите сделать рекурсивную копию. Для этого есть другая функция, [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html).

Если объект содержит другие объекты, которые не позволяют создания копий, то либо переделайте объект так, чтобы он мог копироваться, либо делайте копию вручную. В вашем случае, `pygame.Surface` содержит метод `copy`. Вот [пример использования](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57225764/240613) (на английском, но по самому коду я думаю понятно, что происходит).

Comment: TypeError: cannot pickle 'pygame.Surface' object

Comment: Он выдаёт эту ошибку при copy.deepcopy

Comment: @halwa: См. измененный ответ.